# App content update without user downloading new apk

Tags: javascript, android, ios, video

Hi everyone one I am still new to all this so please bear with me.

I am developing a video based app. How do I add new videos/content into my app without telling user to download new apk. I know I will need to host my app on database but have no idea about it. Can someone direct me to link or explain me the process.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to host your app. You will need a web service and your app will interact with it. Simplest will be hosting a JSON file, update video links/content, etc in that and let your app access and parse that file to get the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

The app should be communicating data via web services (API). eg. On your home page, you have 5 videos being displayed, the link of those videos should be sent via the api.
API will be hosted server side, you next time you need to change the videos, you will just change the response sent by the API.

Comment: Any tutorial recommendations I can read or watch????